# install QT ubuntu OS raspberry pi

Tags: qt-creator

Hi is there anyone know how to install QT to ubuntu OS with raspberry pi 4. I try to install QT in Ubuntu 18.04 but there is error say '/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2': no such file or directory'. I download QT software from the website and try to run it but nothing appear. and when I try to run using terminal it give this '/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2': no such file or directory' error. Does anyone know how to install it?

Comment: Why didn't you download the wanted libraries from Ubuntu repositories?  though as Qt is found in 'universe' it's *out-of-support* for 18.04 (*bionic*) as it's 3 years of supported life are over (the oldest supported system is now 20.04 as used by Lubuntu/Kubuntu/.. with Qt LTS 5.12.8)   Also note the library expected is the x86-64 package and **not** the arm64/armv7 package that will run on the pi 4.  A r.pi is ARM architecture and **not** amd64.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [official repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic-updates/qtbase-opensource-src). To install Qt for development purposes open terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential qtcreator qt5-default qtbase5-dev qtbase5-dev-tools
```